# Hive table with dynamic number of columns

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, analytics, bigdata

```
TestTable
inputsCOLUMN       
3-300-150-150-R     
3-200-100-100-A     
5-500-00-500-A


output
 3_open   3_spent   3_closing   3_type   5_open   5_spent   5_closing   5_type
-------- --------- ----------- -------- -------- --------- ----------- --------
   300    150       150         R        500      00        500         A
   200    100       100         A
```

Above is the input table called TestTable. It has two columns that contains rows of data(strings)
And there is a desired output table of which the column names are based on the input string.
the column name is the first number on the string + another string name, like `CONCAT(split(inputsCOLUMN,'\\-')[0],'-','type')`

so that output is the desired output. and the below query is not working as desired because of that part when i am trying to concatenate an alias i think is not allowed. so help me if there is a way i can find that desired output.

```
SELECT split(inputsCOLUMN,'\\-')[1] as CONCAT(split(inputsCOLUMN,'\\-')[0],'-','open'),
       split(inputsCOLUMN,'\\-')[2] as CONCAT(split(inputsCOLUMN,'\\-')[0],'-','spent'),
       split(inputsCOLUMN,'\\-')[3] as CONCAT(split(inputsCOLUMN,'\\-')[0],'-','closing'),
       split(inputsCOLUMN,'\\-')[4] as CONCAT(split(inputsCOLUMN,'\\-')[0],'-','type')
```

Comment: i tried to manipulate alias such that it contain ID, but it fails

Comment: please restructure the question properly

Answer (score 3):

Hive cannot have a dynamic number of columns, and it cannot have dynamic column names. It must be able to determine the entire schema (column count, types, and names) at query planning time, without looking at any data.

It's also not clear to me how exactly you're matching up input records into a single row. For example, how do you know which "3" record corresponds to which "5" record.

If you knew that, for example, there would always be a "3" record and a "5" record and you could commit to those being the only column names, and if you had a consistent way of matching up records to "flatten" this data, then it is possible, but difficult. I've done almost this exact operation before, and it involved a custom UDTF and a custom UDAF, and some code to auto-generate the actual query, which ended up being hundreds of lines long in some cases. I would re-evaluate why you want to do this in the first place and see if you can come up with another approach.

Comment: Thanks for your  response Joe,

Comment: For clarity please try and check my query statement, it shows exactly what i want and it again show where the problem is.   My main problem is to concatenate ID from data to a string to make an alias.

Comment: But UDTF AND UDAF can only change the number of rows not columns.